Using T-SQL for extracting from JSON
I am trying to extract data from the following JSON and pivot the data in "rows" to columns.
{
"tables": [
    {
        "name": "PrimaryResult",
        "columns": [
            {
                "name": "timestamp",
                "type": "datetime"
            },
            {
                "name": "message",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "severityLevel",
                "type": "int"
            },
            {
                "name": "FriendlySeverityLevel",
                "type": "string"
            },
            {
                "name": "CycleId",
                "type": "dynamic"
            }
        ],
        "rows": [
            [
                "2024-07-25T12:00:00",
                "Report Started - User: user1@test.com MrmClient: 400600 CcID: 000a000b-0000-111c-0a0b-11111a1111a1",
                1,
                "Information",
                "000a000b-0000-111c-0a0b-11111a1111a1"
            ],
            [
                "2024-07-24T12:00:00",
                "Report Started - User: user2@test.com MrmClient: 807231 CcID: 000c000d-0000-11c1-0c0d-11111b11111b",
                1,
                "Information",
                "000c000d-0000-11c1-0c0d-11111b11111b"
            ]
        ]
    }
]

}
This is what I'm trying to get for the final result:

Using JSON_VALUE(RawJSON, '$.tables[0].name') gives me PrimaryResult but I can't figure out how to pull the data from "rows".  I've tried JSON_VALUE(RawJSON, '$.tables[0].rows[0]'), but it returns a NULL.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

rows is an array of arrays.
you want something like this;
SELECT JSON_VALUE(RawJSON, '$.tables[0].rows[0][0]') as timestamp;
SELECT JSON_VALUE(RawJSON, '$.tables[0].rows[0][1]') as message;

Read the docs on OPENJSON function

If the provided JSON content contains information about more than one table, a possible approach is a dynamic statement. The idea is to generate a statement which uses OPENJSON() with the appropriate columns definitions for each table using the information from the $.tables[*].columns parts in the input JSON.
Test JSON with information for two tables:
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = '{
    "tables": [
        {
        "name": "PrimaryResult",
        "columns": [
            {"name": "timestamp", "type": "datetime"},
            {"name": "message", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "severityLevel", "type": "int"},
            {"name": "FriendlySeverityLevel", "type": "string"},
            {"name": "CycleId", "type": "dynamic"}
        ],
        "rows": [
            ["2024-07-25T12:00:00", "Report Started - User: user1@test.com MrmClient: 400600 CcID: 000a000b-0000-111c-0a0b-11111a1111a1", 1, "Information", "000a000b-0000-111c-0a0b-11111a1111a1"],
            ["2024-07-24T12:00:00", "Report Started - User: user2@test.com MrmClient: 807231 CcID: 000c000d-0000-11c1-0c0d-11111b11111b", 1, "Information", "000c000d-0000-11c1-0c0d-11111b11111b"]
        ]
        },
        {
        "name": "SecondaryResult",
        "columns": [
            {"name": "timestamp", "type": "datetime"}
        ], 
        "rows": [
            ["2024-07-25T12:00:00"]
        ]
        } 
    ]
}';

T-SQL:
-- Dynamic statement
DECLARE @stmt nvarchar(max)
; WITH TablesAndColumnsCTE AS (  
   SELECT t.[key] AS TableIndex, c.*
   FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.tables') t
   CROSS APPLY (
      SELECT 
         [key] AS ColumnIndex, 
         JSON_VALUE([value], '$.name') AS ColumnName, 
         JSON_VALUE([value], '$.type') AS ColumnType
      FROM OPENJSON(t.[value], '$.columns')
   ) c
), StatementsCTE AS (
   SELECT CONCAT(
      N'SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(@json, ''$.tables[', TableIndex, N'].rows'') WITH (',
      STRING_AGG(
         CONCAT(N'[', ColumnName, N'] varchar(max) ''$[', ColumnIndex, N']'''),
         N','
      ) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ColumnIndex),
      N')'
   ) AS Statement
   FROM TablesAndColumnsCTE
   GROUP BY TableIndex
)
SELECT @stmt = STRING_AGG(Statement, N'; ')
FROM StatementsCTE

-- Statement execution
DECLARE @err int  
EXEC @err = sp_executesql @stmt, N'@json nvarchar(max)', @json
IF @err <> 0 PRINT 'Error'

The generated statement, based on the test data, is posted below. All columns are defined as nvarchar(max) columns, but you can easily include the appropriate CASE expression and map the columns data types (datetime, string, int and dynamic in the example) to the appropriate SQL Server data types.
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.tables[0].rows') WITH (
   [timestamp] varchar(max) '$[0]',
   [message] varchar(max) '$[1]',
   [severityLevel] varchar(max) '$[2]',
   [FriendlySeverityLevel] varchar(max) '$[3]',
   [CycleId] varchar(max) '$[4]'
);
SELECT * 
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.tables[1].rows') WITH (
   [timestamp] varchar(max) '$[0]'
)


data
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '{

    "tables": [

        {

            "name": "PrimaryResult",

            "columns": [

                {

                    "name": "timestamp",

                    "type": "datetime"

                },

                {

                    "name": "message",

                    "type": "string"

                },

                {

                    "name": "severityLevel",

                    "type": "int"

                },

                {

                    "name": "FriendlySeverityLevel",

                    "type": "string"

                },

                {

                    "name": "CycleId",

                    "type": "dynamic"

                }

            ],

            "rows": [

                ["2024-07-25T12:00:00", "Report Started - User: user1@test.com MrmClient: 400600 CcID: 000a000b-0000-111c-0a0b-11111a1111a1", 1, "Information", "000a000b-0000-111c-0a0b-11111a1111a1"],

                ["2024-07-24T12:00:00", "Report Started - User: user2@test.com MrmClient: 807231 CcID: 000c000d-0000-11c1-0c0d-11111b11111b", 1, "Information", "000c000d-0000-11c1-0c0d-11111b11111b"]

            ]

        }

    ]

}';


use OPENJSON with With as follows
SELECT *

FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.tables[0].rows')

WITH (

    timestamp DATETIME '$[0]',

    message NVARCHAR(MAX) '$[1]',

    severityLevel INT '$[2]',

    FriendlySeverityLevel NVARCHAR(MAX) '$[3]',

    CycleId NVARCHAR(MAX) '$[4]'

);

dbfiddle
